# Iterate Form fields

Tags: ruby, forms, preferences, formtastic

I have build a module to add translations for each standard topic. Theses topic got many standard options and you can translate it directly in page.

I got an issue with my form about the edit view.

When i display a translation it's repeat all value of the f.input :value each time he have one and i want it to display with the each of standard value.

The question is how i can iterate my input field :value in the form to display only once per standard value and not repeat all value translated by standard value.

when i want create a new one all workings fine. It's just about the iterate field who is repeated how many times he got a field in the table.

the gist for my code :

https://gist.github.com/266562670cd8dab28548

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<%= @preference_topic.preference_topic_options.each_with_index do |option, index|  %>
  <%= f.fields_for option.preference_topic_option_translations.first, option do |translate_form| %>
```

to:

```
<%= @preference_topic.preference_topic_options.each_with_index do |option, index|  %>
  <%= f.fields_for option.preference_topic_option_translations.first || option.preference_topic_option_translations.build, option do |translate_form| %>
```